# Python how to speed up get requests using multiprocess

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

I have some code working that sends a get request and returns a list of 93 parameters and I want to use each one of those to make another get request. The problem is that it takes about 15 minutes to run and I'd like to speed it up. I am using a session object in the requests library but that's not good enough so I want to try multiprocessing but I'm having trouble getting my head around it.

```
import requests

params_url = r'URL'
headers = {
  'authorization': 'Token sdfgsdfgsdfg'
}
response = requests.get(params_url, headers = headers)
data = response.json()
params = data['data']

s = requests.Session()
samp_url = s.get(r'SESSION_URL',headers=headers)

for param in params:
    ent_url = r'SESSION_URL'+param+r'&RESULT_FORMAT'
    resp = s.get(ent_url, headers = headers)
    print(resp)
```

currently as a test i am just printing the response code, but I will need to perform other operations with the data (essentially just combining them all into one dataframe). Each response code is 200 which is good. What is the best way to implement multiprocessing to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

you could try [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html)

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def p_me(param,s):
    ent_url = r'SESSION_URL'+param+r'&RESULT_FORMAT'
    resp = s.get(ent_url, headers = headers)
return resp

w = Parallel(n_jobs=-1,verbose=0)(delayed(p_me)(param,s) for param in params)
```